# can the InvNorm function on calculator calculate P(X>x)=value?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

If I have a Variable with normal distribution, can the InvNorm on calculator calculate $P(X>x)$=value, or does it **only** calculate $P(X < x)$=value??

I'm asking this because I have a question that asks the inferior limit of my variable correspondent to the probability $0.95$. And I am doing it like this:

$$P(X < x)=0.95 $$
$$ 1-P(X \ge x)=0.95$$
$$P(X\ge x)=0.05$$

Then I went to the calculator and did InvNorm(0.05, μ, σ).

Can you clarify me about this? Can the InvNorm be used to find the inferior limit? or only the superior limit: $$P(X < x)=value$$

Comment: I still don't fully understand your question. $P(X<x)=1-P(X>x)$ and so it's ok if you can calculate one of these two probabilities, the other one is easily derivable from that.

Comment: Forget the expressions that you can derivate. You can do InvNorm(value, miu, sigma) when you want to find "x" , P(X<x)=value.  But, can you do InvNorm to find "x" , being "x" an inferior limit , P(X>x)=value ? Does InvNorm give you inferior limits or superior limits? Does InvNorm **only** give you the "x" where the area below the graph is only the left part relative to "x", or can it give the right part? @Mesmerizedstudent

Comment: Ok, what calculator you are using? I can't really answer in general, it seems like your question is pretty exact.

Comment: @Mesmerizedstudent I already know the answer. InvNorm only gives a superior limit